# Replacing last week's date with this week's

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm trying to use vba to replace last week's date with this week's to update figures. I've tried the below but I don't think I'm understanding how the replace function works in VBA.

```
Dim lastweek As String
lastweek = Format(Now - 7, "yyyymmdd")
Dim thisweek As String
thisweek = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")
Replace (lastweek,lastweek,thisweek)
```

Also, am I using the correct formula for last week where I want to pull the date for 7 days ago?

Comment: What you are doing above is equivalent to `lastweek=thisweek`? It's unclear what you are asking please elaborate with example!

Comment: I have formulas that pull data from sheets saved down weekly, so every friday I need to update the date by replacing last weeks date with today. So today I am trying to replace `20140919` with `20140926, but I already run a macro on the sheet so I want the replace function to also be part of it

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the `Replace` function.  If I ran `Replace("This is a cat.", "cat", "dog")` the result would be `"This is a dog."`.  Replace operates on a String and returns a String. If you want to apply it to a Range of cells, a whole Worksheet or even a whole Workbook, you'll need to do something a bit different.  In fact, odds are you want to use Excel's built-in Find/Replace functionality instead.

Comment: Ah - that makes more sense! I do want the built-in Replace! I'll give that a try now

Comment: Where are the dates you are trying to replace?

Comment: I want it to be a formula so I can apply it weekly when I run the macro.

`='H:\Schemes\Weekly Centre Status Report\ACOS - CCA\[20140919 ACOS-CCA.xlsx]ACOS - CCA'!$C$8`

For example I want to change the date there `20140919` to be todays date `20140926`, so that the cell now pulls data from todays sheets

Answer (score 2):

Convert the last week to Date and add 7 days to it, to get next week value

```
Function MyWeek(lastweek As String) As String
lw = DateSerial(CInt(Left(lastweek, 4)), CInt(Mid(lastweek, 5, 2)), CInt(Right(lastweek, 2)))
MyWeek = Format(lw + 7, "yyyymmdd")
End Function
```

Then use,

```
=REPLACE(A1,SEARCH("2*]",A1,1),8,Myweek(MID(A1,SEARCH("2*]",A1,1),8)))
```

to replace the date with new date, assuming your string to be replaced is in the Cell `A1`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use auto-filter option in VBA. Just paste the below code in a Module as follows:

```
Sub date_change()
Dim filter_column As Range
Dim start_date As Date
Dim end_date As Date

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Set filter_column = .Range("j1")    'give the column which has the date that needs to be changed
    end_date = Now - Weekday(Now, vbSunday)
    end_date = DateSerial(Year(end_date), Month(end_date), Day(end_date))
    start_date = end_date - 6
    start_date = DateSerial(Year(start_date), Month(start_date), Day(start_date))
    .Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=filter_column.Column, Criteria1:=">=" & start_date, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & end_date
    .Range(.Cells(2, filter_column.Column), .Cells(.Rows.Count, filter_column.Column).End(xlUp)).Select

        If WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Selection) <> 1 Then
            Selection.ClearContents
            Selection = Now
        End If

End With
```

End Sub